# When I make my attacks of opportunity with my X-laser, do I get to shoot a line?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, ranged-attack

So my 6th level scryer/slayer/gunslinger's bonded object is a masterwork X-laser.  Our party has an awesome flowing monk with Greater Reposition.  I have Snap Shot, Combat Reflexes, and a very high Dex mod.  Thusly, the first 8 times a round the monk repositions an enemy (which he does a *lot* but, admittedly, not usually more than 8 times a round) I get a free potshot, as long as the repositioned enemy is within my maximum range.

What I'm wondering is if should actually be rolling the AoOs like regular X-laser shots (lines extending from me to maximum range) rather than as a single target effect like I do right now.  On the one hand, the X-laser states:

> When making an attack with an x-laser, make a single attack roll and compare that result to the ACs of all creatures in a line extending out to the weapon's maximum range.

On the other hand, AoO are specifically directed at the character that provoked them, presumably to somewhat mitigate bag-of-rats fightering:

> In this case [where she has provoked an attack of opportunity], combatants near her can take advantage of her lapse in defense to attack her for free.

We're pretty far from 'normal' attacks of opportunity anyways, since being repositioned provokes attacks from people even if they don't threaten the enemy's squares *and* I can make attacks of opportunity with a ranged weapon *and* I can make more than one per turn, so I'm thinking the former of the two statements is actually more compelling here, but I'm not sure.

When I make an AoO with my X-laser do I attack all things in a line or just the provoking opponent?

Comment: What is an X-laser?

Comment: Oh, dear.  I thought only the railgun did that.  The X-laser hits a massive line, too, and doesn't have the slow-firing trait.  This is bad.  (Note that without some serious tricks to increase its capacity or reduce its power usage, you only get four shots before you have to recharge it.)  @Brian, it is [terrifying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/technological-weapons#TOC-X-Laser).

Comment: @gatherer818 Yah, she's a sniper. And even so some minor tricks are necessary so she gets 4 shots a round every round instead of once.

Comment: The DM permitted the character a masterwork X-laser (40,300 gp; 10 lbs.) for the [scryer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/divination/scryer)'s bonded object *via* [arcane bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-Bond-Ex-or-Sp-)? That, sir, is *shameless.* I applaud you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Weapons function normally during attacks of opportunity

Your *+3 [flaming](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming) short sword* still deals fire damage during an attack of opportunity, and your foe will really regret drinking that potion when, during the attack of opportunity he provokes for chugging, you lop off his head with your *+1 keen [vorpal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/vorpal) scimitar*.

In other words, using a weapon off-turn doesn't change how the weapon behaves. When you make an attack of opportunity with your [X-laser](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/technological-weapons#TOC-X-Laser), that's your attack roll against everything in a 2,000-ft. line.

You are likely no longer your neighbors' friend. Or the *town's* friend.

Comment: *GURPS*, BTW, calls it a *xaser* (therefore further shortening *X-laser* from *X-ray laser*), which is a lot more fun to say ("Zaser! Zaser!") than *X-laser*, which sounds like a laser that snowboards.